# R: Partially overlapping ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm graphing 21 channels of time-series data together in a plot. See image below. As you can see the waveforms are quite flat because they're limited to their respective graphs. Is there some way to allow the graphs to partially overlap with the graphs above and below? Or to allow the lines to exceed their graphs and 'spill over' above or below?

My graph currently looks as follows:

[image]

Code:

```
png("spectral_all_channels.png", units="in", width=16, height=12, res=300)
mdf <- melt(data=EEG, id="X")
ggplot(data=mdf, mapping=aes(x=X, y=value)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(min(mdf["value"]), max(mdf["value"]))) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left=element_text(angle = 0),
        text = element_text(size = 26) +
  labs(x="Time (s)") +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ .,
             switch = "y") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(start_s*256, end_s*256, 2560), labels=seq(start_s, end_s, 10))
dev.off()
```

An example of the desired effect:

[image]

Comment: We would need some data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of way you might attempt this. One is use something like [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) to set up your plots in a grid that overlaps with one another.

The other option is to use a different kind of plot like a ridgeplot. See [ggridges](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html). But as @TarJae said w/o knowing what your endgoal is and some dummy data it's kinda hard to give working example